# What Windows Form control would be a good fit for this use case?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm going create an open source Help desk solution free of charge for small to medium businesses to use.

I'm currently working on the client application.

I want to have a list of tickets that have been opened by the user. So it would be like a table TicketsByUser:

```
Ticket Number | Type      | Description    | Date       | Handled?
123456        | Hardware  | My mouse broke | 10/20/2010 | No
123457        | software  | Opera broke    | 10/20/2010 | Yes
```

I was thinking of using ListView because of it's name, but I have **zero** experience with it, so maybe it's not what I'm looking for.

I'm going to be pulling the data from a WCF service which in turn pulls it from a MS SQL database.

**Edit:** 
All information is going to be modified (really only the Handled option though) on the Server (IT helper) side.

The client cannot modify anything, it's meant as only a Windows to view previous tickets. :) Taking that into account, what would you recommend?

Comment: ListView with View = Details is the proper control for this.  It is read-only by design.  You should learn how to use it sooner or later, might as well make it sooner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listview would probably be ok, but I'd also consider a DataGridView.

Listview might be slightly easier to use, but DataGridView is a bit more flexible, from your short description a ListView is probably enough though. However, if you want the users to be able to update the data in the table (for example use a tickbox in the *Handled* column that they can tick when it's been handled) then a DataGridView is probably more suitable.

Comment: Actually, ListView is harder to use if the list can change.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking for a basic readonly list for someone that's a bit new to it its a bit easier to get started with.

Comment: Setting a DataGridView to read only in VS.NET is a single mouse click I believe...

Comment: @Kyle: Close.  It's two mouse clicks.  (One to get the smart tag)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k39d6s23%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) control; it can use databinding to automatically display and update your datasource, and can optionally allow the users to edit it.

The ListView control has very limited editing capabilities, and is far more difficult to work with.